# Will I still be afflicted with vampirism if I delay becoming a Vampire Lord?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I deny the first offer to become a vampire, and stay with the Dawngaurd, then later become a vampire lord, does my blood still boil in the sun?

Just wondering as I need to figure out all the pros and cons before I make my decision.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. After you choose to become a vampire lord, you will be afflicted with vampirism, which will (at later stages) cause the active affect "Your blood boils in the sun."

I would suggest reading more about vampirism [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Vampirism_(Skyrim)) before you make your decision.